# Code outputs nonsense to output file instead of string?

Tags: c++, string, file, filestream, stringstream

The following code is for a project I have to do where I recieve a text file that has a students first and last name followed by his grades. I then have to convert that into an output file that contains his name followed by his average score. The file I recieve has multiple students in it spereated line by line. The output should look relativly like

```
Rzam, Look           = 0.00
Bambi, Lambi         = 40.47
Coop, Jason          = 27.31
```

but mine is merely printing garbage such as

0x7fffb08e8698= 0.000x7fffb08e8698= 0.000x7fffb08e8698= 0.000x7fffb08e8698=       0.000x7fffb08e8698= 0.000x7fffb08e8698= 0.000x7fffb08e8698= 0.000x7fffb08e8698= 0.000x7fffb08e8698= 0.000x7fffb08e8698= 0.00

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Student
{
    string fname;
    string lname;
    double average;
};

int read(ifstream &fin, Student s[]);

void print(ofstream &fout, Student s[], int amount);


int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    string inputFile;
    string outputFile;
    Student s[size];

    cout << "Enter input filename: ";
    cin >> inputFile;
    cout << "Enter output filename: ";
    cin >> outputFile;
    cout << endl;

    fin.open(inputFile.c_str());
    fout.open(outputFile.c_str());

    read(fin , s);
    print(fout, s, size);

    fin.close();
    fout.close();

}

int read(ifstream &fin, Student s[])
{
    string line;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    double score;
    double total;
    int i=0;
    int totalStudents=0;
    Student stu;

    while(getline(fin, line)){
        istringstream sin;
        sin.str(line);

        while(sin >> firstName >> lastName){
            stu.fname = firstName;
            stu.lname = lastName;

            while(sin >> score){
            total *= score;
            i++;
            }
            stu.average = (total/i);
        }
        s[totalStudents]=stu;
        totalStudents++;
    }
    return totalStudents;
}

void print(ofstream &fout, Student s[], int amount)
{
    ostringstream sout;
    for(int i = 0; i<amount; i++)
    {
        sout << left << setw(20) << s[i].lname << ", " << s[i].fname;
        fout << sout << setprecision(2) << fixed << "= " << s[i].average;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you call memory addresses garbage...Try using c_str() for fname and lname strings... E.g. `s[i].fname.c_str()`

Comment: tried but to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few bugs, which have added up to your issue:

1. in your `print` function, you write to a `ostringstream` and then try to write that to the file stream. Which is fine, but it is printing the address of the `ostringstream` buffer. So making this change will cause it to print the contents:

   ```
   fout << sout.str() << setprecision(2) << fixed << "= " << s[i].average;
   ```

Note the usage of `.str()`. Though you don't really need a temporary stream here at all...

2. You don't place a newline in the output, so it all ends up one line making it hard to read:

so make another change making it look like this:

```
fout << sout.str() << setprecision(2) << fixed << "= " << s[i].average << '\n';
```

3. You need to place the `ostringstream sout;` inside the loop, so it is reset each time too. Otherwise you will get weirdly compounding output.
4. You don't use the count of students calculated by your read function! so it always tries to print 10! Do something like this:

   ```
   int count = read(fin , s);
   print(fout, s, count);
   ```
5. If no score is read, I think you'll have a divide by zero. So you should add a check.
6. You should ensure that no more than `size` Students are read. Or better yet, just place them in a `std::vector` and return that from the function. It's simpler and less error prone.
7. You need to reset `i` each time you start reading a student, or the later students will get divided by way too much. Each needs to have an independent count.

I don't know if these are the only issues, but certainly it should get you started on the right track :-)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. This is my first college level comp sci class so it means a lot

Comment: No problem. I also just noticed one more minor thing that I'll edit into the answer. Best of luck!

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged, while your code had several issues, it also did a lot of things right! `while(getline(fin, line)){` is a beautiful pattern that I wish more new c++ developers new to use! You used `std::string` where appropriate instead of juggling raw buffers too.

Comment: Thank you again for all of this. I really wish to succeed in this class although at times i can get pretty lost.